# Blender: Copy active vertex position to selected vertex position and mirror axis

Tags: python, scripting, blender, 3d-modelling

The basic question is how to write a simple script that copies one vertex position to another vertex and mirrors one axis, as well as copying and mirroring all vertex weights if possible.

Two selected vertices should be mirrored, but due to user error, are slightly off and break the mirror symmetry in edit mode.

I have tried using the symmetrize function already in blender, but this breaks weight painting values for the model and leaves duplicate vertices behind. Manually copying every x,y,z position and vertex weight is not efficient at all.

Comment: Have you tried deleting half and adding a mirror modifier? It can copy UV's to the mirror. Have you tried [edit mode mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/mirror.html)? or [mirror topology](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh_options.html#topology-mirror)?

Comment: Yes, trying to use the mirror modifier is what led to the problem in the first place, because as I said before, it breaks weight painting values and leaves behind extra vertices that a threshold won't cover. Edit mode axis mirroring and mirror topology don't work once the vertices are already out of place.